# Mac terminal command: how to 'ls' for some specific files?

Tags: mac, terminal

My question is about the ls command. If I have too many files in a folder, I might need either:

1. ls files with a given type only or;
2. ls files within a range, i.e., files with names a* to b*.

Answer (score 12):

```
ls *.jpg # files whose name ends with .jpg
ls [ab]* # files whose name starts with a or b
ls [a-c]* # files whose name starts with characters sorted between a and c in the current locale
ls|head -n100 # first 100 files
f=(*);printf %s\\n "${f[@]:0:100}" # first 100 files
ls|sed -n 101,200p # files 101 to 200
find . -name \*aa\* # files whose name contains aa in the directory tree
find . ! -type d # all files except directories in the directory tree
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 # regular files in the current directory
shopt -s extglob;printf %s\\n !(*aa*) # files whose name does not contain aa
shopt -s extglob;printf %s\\n @(aa|bb)* # files whose name starts with aa or bb
```

Comment: What about I wannt ls files that are NOT in some criteria?

Comment: I edited the answer. If you use bash, add `shopt -s extglob` to `~/.bash_profile`, and then you can for example use `!(prefix*)` to list files that don't start with `prefix`.